# Python, next iteration of the loop over a loop

Tags: python

I need to get the next item of the first loop given certain condition, but the condition is in the inner loop. Is there a shorter way to do it than this? (test code)

```
    ok = 0
    for x in range(0,10):
        if ok == 1:
            ok = 0
            continue
        for y in range(0,20): 
            if y == 5:
                ok = 1
                continue
```

What about in this situation?

```
for attribute in object1.__dict__:
    object2 = self.getobject()
    if object2 is not None:
        for attribute2 in object2: 
            if attribute1 == attribute2:
                # Do something
                #Need the next item of the outer loop
```

The second example shows better my current situation. I dont want to post the original code because it's in spanish. object1 and object2 are 2 very different objects, one is of object-relational mapping nature and the other is a webcontrol. But 2 of their attributes have the same values in certain situations, and I need to jump to the next item of the outer loop.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Replace the `continue` in the inner loop with a `break`. What you want to do is to actually break out of the inner loop, so a `continue` there does the opposite of what you want.

```
ok = 0
for x in range(0,10):
    print "x=",x
    if ok == 1:
        ok = 0
        continue
    for y in range(0,20): 
        print "y=",y
        if y == 5:
            ok = 1
            break
```

Comment: true, my mistake. but I still need to see if I can get the next item of the outer loop in a simpler way :)

Comment: @Pablo: getting back to the outer loop immediately is the same as breaking out of the inner loop, isn't it? Or did you mean something else?

Comment: @Pablo: I guess you want to avoid using `break`. I don't think there is any other way to go back to the outer loop from a `for` loop. The only way that comes to mind is to use a `while` loop where the looping condition checks for there truth of a flag. This is essentially what ron suggested, and you can easily run a while loop over an iterable like a  `for` loop using an explicit `iterator`.

Comment: It is in the case you dont have code after the inner loop. In the other case, it isnt. But that could work for me now if I modify something plus in your example you dont need the ok flag anymore. 
Thanks, Im going to accept yours as the answer, it is pretty much close to what I want

Answer (score 2):

Your example code is equivalent to (that doesn't seem what you want):

```
for x in range(0, 10, 2):
    for y in range(20): 
        if y == 5:
           continue
```

To skip to the next item without using `continue` in the outer loop:

```
it = iter(range(10))
for x in it:
    for y in range(20):
        if y == 5:
           nextx = next(it)
           continue
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always transform into a while loop:

```
flag = False
for x in range(0, 10):
    if x == 4: 
        flag = True
        continue
```

becomes

```
x = 0
while (x != 4) and x < 10:
    x += 1
flag = x < 10
```

Not necessary simpler, but nicer imho.

Comment: Thanks, but I posted a bad example. In my current situation I'm working with objects instead of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

So you're not after something like this? I'm assuming that you're looping through the keys to a dictionary, rather than the values, going by your example.

```
for i in range(len(object1.__dict__)):
  attribute1 = objects1.__dict__.keys()[i]
  object2 = self.getobject() # Huh?
  if object2 is not None:
    for j in range(len(object2.__dict__)):
      if attribute1 == object2.__dict__.keys()[j]:
        try:
          nextattribute1 = object1.__dict__.keys()[i+1]
        except IndexError:
          print "Ran out of attributes in object1"
          raise
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear to me what you want, but if you're testing something for each item produced in the inner loop, `any` might be what you want ([docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any))

```
>>> def f(n):  return n % 2
... 
>>> for x in range(10):
...     print 'x=', x
...     if f(x):
...         if any([y == 8 for y in range(x+2,10)]):
...             print 'yes'
... 
x= 0
x= 1
yes
x= 2
x= 3
yes
x= 4
x= 5
yes
x= 6
x= 7
x= 8
x= 9
```